# Iterating over an array of tuples using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working through a quiz on the website ExecuteProgram.com for learning Typescript, and I'm a bit stuck, and I haven't been able to find help via documentation.

The question wants the following input to the function to run correctly to return both names:

```
names([['Amir', 34], ['Betty', 17]]);
```

The problem statement is posed as such:

> Write a function that takes an array of tuples. Each tuple consists of a name (a string) and an age (a number). Your function should return only the names.

My function is as follows, but doesn't seem to be able to return all of the names, just the first one.

```
function names(people: [string, number][]) {
    for (const [name, age] of people) {
       return name;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the `for` loop above be iterating over the entire array of `people` and returning each name? It seems like it's only returning the first item in the array.

Comment: The problem is that as soon as you call `return`, your function gets terminated. If you just print out the name to the console and don't call `return`, you'll see that your function works as expected.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks for the explanation, I didn't realize I was short-circuiting it.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to extract elements from a list, my advise is to use the [map functon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?retiredLocale=it).

In this case the code will be

```
const tuples: [string, number][] = [['Amir', 34], ['Betty', 17]];

function get_name(person: [string, number]) {
    return person[0];
}

console.log(tuples.map(tuple => get_name(tuple)));
```

The element before the arrow represents the single element in your array of tuples (see the function signature) and the entire function is returning a new array which is the result of the applied function on each element.

I like this approach also because is not modifying in place your array!

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCuAHANgUwgLhgbWgJwEswBzAGhjHgFsAjVPAXWwZgF4dsByAQSoL07kAzABYG5LgCFUUKAE9BMAIwB2BgwDcAKC0AzeGGBQC4GMRkB9MAEMqqABSJ6EcFlxRCJcpVr0GAShgAby0YMJg8GXg8MBgnPBcwbAAGTS0AXx1QSBA0ADpkEGJ7BBR0PKprRBKkNDYAPjNLGzsasv8OjSA) you can find a playground with the working code!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
function* names(people: [string, number][]) {
    for (const [name, age] of people) {
       yield name;
    }
}
```

See here: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-beta#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mAVAAjAQwLYFMDOAKAByzgIBssAuZAbRygCcYwBzAGlRAwCMt6BdanwCUyAN4AoZFOTA49ZHggI6NdNnZpmWPsjjBkREuRETpZgJ4wspACapMWANyTpAX3Hvxs%20XnJR72Lr6arh41NQA5ACCGDD0EewAzAAsfOyRAEJYUFDmCcgAjADsfMJCLlJKYDhw5AB0pHDMeCFCjkA)

`return` only returns one value.

`yield` lets you return multiple.

**EDIT:** `function*` tells the js engine that you're going to return multiple values.